# Reading/Writing from a text file to a linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

so I'm making a program that takes in data on an employee (id, name etc.) I've got most of what I have off a sanfoundry tutorial and now I'm just wondering how I save the employee records I've created in a text file. And of course how I'd open that text file when running the program at the beginning.

I'm able to do this normally but I'm finding it very difficult to implement it into the code from the tutorial.

```
FILE *file =        fopen("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\AdvProgrammingAssignment\\employees.txt", "r");

char c;

if(file == NULL) {
    printf("Error, file not found");
}

do {
    c = fgetc(file);
    printf("%c", c);
}
while(c != EOF);

fclose(file);
```

This would work for reading in (it's from another program I did) But now that I'm trying to add onto what the tutorial does and have the linked list write to a text file when exiting I'm a bit clueless.

This is the code from the tutorial(not all of it)

```
void main()
{
struct emp_data *linkList;
char name[21], desig[51], addre[25], hd[15], empEmail[15], empSal[10];
char choice;
int eno;

linkList = NULL;
printf("\n Welcome to the employee database \n");

menu();

do
{
    /*  choose oeration to be performed */
    choice = option();
    switch(choice)
    {
    case '1':
        printf("\n Enter the Employee Number      : ");
        scanf("%d", &eno);
        printf("Enter the Employee name        : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(name);
        printf("Enter the Employee Department : ");
        gets(desig);
        printf("Enter the Employee Address : ");
        gets(addre);
        printf("Enter the Employee Hire Date : ");
        gets(hd);
        printf("Enter the Employee Email : ");
        gets(empEmail);
        printf("Enter the Employee Salary : ");
        gets(empSal);

        linkList = insert(linkList, eno, name, desig, addre, hd, empEmail,     empSal);
        break;
    case '2':
        printf("\n\n Enter the employee number to be deleted: ");
        scanf("%d", &eno);
        linkList = deleteNode(linkList, eno);
        break;
    case '3':
        if (linkList == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n Database empty.");
            break;
        }
        display(linkList);
        break;
    case '4':
        printf("\n\n Enter the employee number to be searched: ");
        scanf("%d", &eno);
        search(linkList, eno);
        break;
    case '5': break;
    }
} while (choice != '5');
}
```

Should I create a new method and call it at the beginning of the main? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int` (not a `char`)

Comment: Okay... Any ideas on how I'd get my problem solved?

Comment: `int fgetc( std::FILE* stream )` ..  [link]For further information http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc

Comment: Your exactly problem is that the reading is incorrect? Or you get a particular exception/error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might be understanding this wrong but, if the only thing you are wanting to do is to create a text file and write data into said text file, an easy option would simply be :

```
fd = open(pathToYourFile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

On windows that would create a file with, as rights :

user : Read+Write

allOthers : Read.

For Unix you will have to specify for group and others so it would look like :

```
fd = open(pathToYourFile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IROTH | S_IRGRP);
```

Also, O_TRUNC is just to truncate the file so as to write only the information you want in it. Look around the open man for more information.

If you want fopen its shorter. Just do

```
file = fopen(PathToYourFile, 'w+');
```

Then all you have to do is write to the file. (So either to fd, an int, or to file, a FILE *)